# How to Filter rows in table with JSON column values - Sequalize, mySql

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

i need to filter the table by using order.id  which is nested 2 levels deeper inside the item column
can we filter them in sequalize

i don't know how to filter them

code:

```
item: datatype.jsonb
```

```
item:[{
   Order:[
         {
           id: 01,  
           name: xxxx,
         },
         {
           id:02,
           name:yyyy,
         }
       ]
  }]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
model.findAll({
    where: {
        '$item.Order.id$': 2;
    },
    include: [{ model: item, include: [{ model: Order}] }]
})
```

You can filter them using outer where condition if you want to filter whole data setup according to that where condition, otherwise you can add where condition inside include object like this

```
model.findAll({
    include: [{ model: item, include: [{ model: Order, where: { id: 2 } }] }]
})
```

Comment: actually this is not working
i think this code refers that the item is an associated model

but in my case item is an column which is in same db
and that column is a jsonb datatype
so i stored order object
inside it 
that order is not associated

Comment: So, In the sequelize table, you cannot directly filter on column with JSON datatype. First you should have to collect data and then process it.